# Clicking a button using xpath with contains option

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

[image]I have a page where i need to click specific button meeting the condition for which i have written the code accordingly but however the problem arises when contains condition is not met for clicking the button event becuase i get a InvaliSelectorException i believe i am doing something wrong in the matter of writing the xpath.

in the page that i am scraping there are multiple rows with four columns each so for each row i have each element of the column appended to the list respectively and check the condition on the button's text for delivery cost using enumerate with which i get the index of the list where the text of the button is view delivery cost for those with these text i want to check all the values and like the first element ,second element,third element,fourth element and then click the element in the td of the row where all these conditions are present

```
for row in rows:
    try:
        SizeOfContainer = row.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-size"]/span').text.replace('Double \n Doors', "")
        SizeOfContainer1 = SizeOfContainer.replace('HC', "")
        SizeOfContainer2 = SizeOfContainer1.replace('Double Doors', "")
        SizeOfContainer3 = SizeOfContainer2.replace('\n', "")
        SizeOfContainer4 = SizeOfContainer3.replace('DoubleDoors', "")
        print(SizeOfContainer4)
        SizeOfContainers.append(SizeOfContainer4)
        Ranking = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[2]/b').text
        Ranking1 = Ranking.replace('\n',"")
        print(Ranking1)
        Rankingofcont.append(Ranking1)
        Price = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[3]/h4').text
        pricelist.append(Price)
        print(Price)
        DeliveryAvailable = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[4]').text
        print(DeliveryAvailable)
        deliveryav.append(DeliveryAvailable)
        CityName = DeliveryAvailable.replace("Yes, to","")
        try:
            delsta = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[5]/a/b').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            delsta = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[5]/form/button/b').text
        print(delsta)
        delstatus.append(delsta)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    listnumbcond = [i for i, x in enumerate(delstatus) if x == "View Delivery Cost »"]
    print(listnumbcond)
    pricenew=[]
    SizeOfContainersnew = []
    Rankingofcontnew = []
    deliveryavnew = []
    for i in listnumbcond:
        pricenew.append(pricelist[i])
    for i in listnumbcond:
        SizeOfContainersnew.append(SizeOfContainers[i])
    for i in listnumbcond:
        Rankingofcontnew.append(Rankingofcont[i])
    for i in listnumbcond:
        deliveryavnew.append(deliveryav[i])
    print(pricenew)

    for j in pricenew:
        ss = pricenew.index(j)
        print(ss)
        aj = SizeOfContainersnew[ss]
        print(aj)
        ag = Rankingofcontnew[ss]
        print(ag)
        adf = deliveryavnew[ss]
        aj1 = str(aj)
        g = str(j)
        ddjel = "//*[contains(text()," + '"' +aj1 + '"' + ")]"+"//*[contains(text()," + '"' +ag + '"' + ")]"+"//*[contains(text()," + '"' +g + '"'+ ")]"+"'//*[contains(text()," + '"' +adf + '"' + ")]/../[@class="+"'button radius small dropshadowtiny margin4r'"+"]'"
        Delivery_cost = row.find_element_by_xpath(ddjel).click()
        delivery_details()
```

i expect to check the td if the it contains the first text then check for the value of the second text in the next td and then third td text and then foruth td text if all met then click the fifth td button.

all these value to be checked are fetched from a list where i have stored it.

I have attatched the images of the page and its html tag as well[image]

following is the html code :

```
<tr>
<td class="text-center">
    <div class="inline min-120">                                            
        <div id="container-size">
            <a href="/includes/size-guide.php" data-reveal-id="ModalSize" data-reveal-ajax="true">
            <img alt="20 container" id="image-size" src="/img/sizes/20-left.png" class="dropshadowtiny">
            <p id="text-size">&nbsp;<span class="black-text">20'</span>
                                                            </p>
        </a></div><a href="/includes/size-guide.php" data-reveal-id="ModalSize" data-reveal-ajax="true">

        </a>
    </div>


</td>
<td class="text-center">
            <b>WWT (Wind &amp; Water Tight)</b><br>

            <sub><a href="/includes/ratings-guide.php" data-reveal-id="ModalRatings" data-reveal-ajax="true">What's this?</a></sub>
                                                                                            </td>
<td class="text-center">
    <h4><a id="1" data-icon-name="" class="myModalIconJS left"></a>$2,049                                       </h4>
                                        </td>
<td class="text-center">                                        <i class="fi-check style28 size-32"></i><small>Yes, to </small>Abanda                                   </td>
<td class="text-center" nowrap="">
    <form method="post" action="/cart.php" class="no-margin-bottom">                
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <button class="button radius small dropshadowtiny margin4r"><i class="fi-star style20"></i> <b>View Delivery Cost »</b></button>

        <input type="hidden" name="buyer-city_nameid" value="4829438">
        <input type="hidden" name="buyer-state_admincode" value="US.AL">        
        <input type="hidden" name="buyer-country" value="USA">

        <input type="hidden" name="buyer-depot_city" value="Atlanta">
        <input type="hidden" name="buyer-depot_state" value="GA">
        <input type="hidden" name="buyer-depot_country" value="USA">                        

        <input type="hidden" name="items-product_id" value="1-wwt-20-Atlanta">
        <input type="hidden" name="items-quantity" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="items-size" value="20">
        <input type="hidden" name="items-rating" value="wwt">
        <input type="hidden" name="items-price" value="2049">           

        <input type="hidden" name="add_scfs_to_cart" value="yes">                                                                       
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB done can you help now